# Linq Statement Returns Max Lengths of all Columns Filter Other Than String Type

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<int> maximumLengthForColumns =
    Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
              .Select(col => dt.AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(row => row[col])
                               .OfType<string>()
                               .Max(val => val.Length)
                      ).ToList();
```

This Linq statement find the max length of all columns in data table. Can anyone help me to put where clause on columns type. It through exception if the column type is other than string.

Comment: It would really help if you'd fix the indentation - your second `Select`, and the `OfType` and `Max` calls are effectively nested in the first `Select`, but that's far from clear with your current layout. Now, what exception is thrown, and what do you want the result to be for non-string columns?

Comment: Exception is "Sequence contains no elements", Non string columns just ignored

Comment: Right - so please edit all of that information into the question. (It seems odd that you'd *ignore* non-string columns, as that means you can't actually get the maximum length for column X, as you'd need to know how many non-string columns are before it.)

Comment: Worder what is the value of 
List<Type> types = Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
    .SelectMany(col => dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => row[col].GetType()))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a Linq statement will work.  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            List<int> maximumLengthForColumns = new List<int>(dt.Columns.Count);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (row[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
                    {
                        int length = row.Field<string>(i).Count();
                        if (length > maximumLengthForColumns[i])
                            maximumLengthForColumns[i] = length; 
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Reasonably complex series of embedded LINQ queries to achieve this.

Given the following example data -

```
DataTable dtb = new DataTable();

dtb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(string) });
dtb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(int) });
dtb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(bool) });
dtb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(string) });


dtb.Rows.Add(new object[] { "dave", 1, true, "sanderson" });
dtb.Rows.Add(new object[] { "oliver", 1, true, "brown" });
```

The following LINQ clause will return a List of integers (6 and 9) that correspond to the max length of data for columns 1 and 4 (the only columns with a data type of string).

```
var answer =
    (from a in
         (from row in dtb.AsEnumerable() //get all the data rows
          select
               (from col in //filter the columns in i.e. just string ones
                     (from column in dtb.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
                     where column.DataType == typeof(string)
                     select column.Ordinal)
               //build an array holding relavent data i.e. just string values
                select new { col = col, val = row[col] }).ToArray())
                //flaten the data into a single data set
                .SelectMany(m => (from a in m select new { col = a.col, a.val })) 
                group a by a.col into g //group the data by the column
                //as we have grouped by column we can now max the string data's length  
                select g.Max(s => s.val.ToString().Length)).ToList();
```

However splitting them up makes it so much more readable.

```
 //get the string columns from the datatable
 var cols = (from column in dtb.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            where column.DataType == typeof(string)
            select column).ToList();


 //get the row data from the table, using select many to finally flatten back to a flat array of data.
 var rows = (from row in dtb.AsEnumerable()
            select
            (from col in cols
             select new { col = col.Ordinal, val = row[col] }).ToArray()
            ).SelectMany(m => (from a in m select new { col = a.col, a.val })).ToList();


 //group the data by the column and get the max data length
 var answer = (from a in rows
               group a by a.col into g
               select g.Max(s => s.val.ToString().Length)).ToList();
```